# Outsmarting the Devil

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the early to late 1990's, a short story made into an episode of [*The Twilight Zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_(1985_TV_series)), [*Beyond Belief: Fact or Fiction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Belief%3A_Fact_or_Fiction), or possibly [*The Outer Limits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)) was the story of a man's encounter with the ultimate temptation. But I can't pinpoint the exact episode, no search engine seems to lead there.

The Devil (played by an Afro-Caribbean American actor, I recall), offers the man anything his heart desires. The man attempts to politely turn down the foe, but the Devil persists, saying that there must be something that the man wants, the Devil can give him anything, can travel to the beginning and the end of time, from one side to the other of the universe, he knows how to find and retrieve everything and anything that the man wants - so what is the man's dearest wish and the Devil will grant it.

The man refuses again, the Devil persists, saying that he can grant any wish - there is nothing, nothing at all that he cannot do if the man wishes it.

The story ends when the man finally gives-in (sort-of), and tells the Devil his wish: "Get lost" the man said. The look of shocked realization on the Devil's face tells us he knows that the man has won, as it's something he can't do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is ["I of Newton"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_of_Newton), an episode of the 80's revival of *The Twilight Zone*.  It basically goes as you remember:

> Sam asks if there are any physical limitations to the demon's powers, and for his third question, if there is any place from which the demon cannot find his way back. The demon denies any limitation in either regard. Sam then delivers the demon's task, which he has now established that he cannot accomplish: "Get lost."

The demon is played by [Ron Glass](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0322002/).

(Found by Googling "mathematician outer limits devil 'get lost'" (I had recalled reading the Wikipedia article on this episode and remembered that the man was a mathematician))

Comment: Yep, that's the one Ron Glass was so different then that I didn't recognize him by the time Firefly came along. My oh my, that was quick too. I'll wait the customary 24/48 before awarding the tick. Much appreciated, it's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: One of my favorite stories from the 1980s *Twilight Zone*, with Ron Glass and Sherman Hemsley!

Comment: Kind of the same logic as the classic "I am lying" trick against Mudd's androids in ST:TOS.